# Tactic cards in combat in Warhammer: Invasion

Tags: warhammer-invasion

Look at the following combat scenario:

1. Both players had counted their forces strength and assigned the damage to opponents forces (assigned but not yet applied)
2. Now according to the rules players can play Tactics cards (as in between every other combat phases).

The question is: can one player play now the tactics card that will give him extra strength? The damage has been assigned already and having this ability would move the game back to previous phase (damage assignment) but the rule book doesn't clarify this subject.

Answer (score 1):

The rules don't state anywhere that you can roll back to a previous phase, and the core rules and FAQ don't explicitly cover this scenario.

I would say that while you **can** play a card that gives him extra strength, there will be **no net effect** since damage has already been applied, and once damage is applied, that's it.